# Submit values with link_to in Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So currently i have a link_to, where signed in users can click on:

```
<%= link_to "Enroll", [@task.project, @task] %>
```

The user has an association with the project, through subscription. To create a new subscription for a user with a project, i wrote some simple form for it.

```
<%= form_for([@project, @subzz]) do |f| %>



        <%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => @project.id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

Which works fine and creates the association. However, i want that the user is able to create the subscription whenever he clicks on 'enroll' instead of a second, extra submit button.

Any ideas how to approach this? I thought about using jQuery, but not sure how to inject the ids with it and if its the 'right' way to do it.

Thanks in advance everyone!

EDIT:

When using the method posted as answer, i get:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: sub
```

My updatet form:

```
  <%= form_for([@project, @subzz], html: {role: "form", id: "project_form"}) do |f| %>

        <%= hidden_field_tag :project_id, :value => @project.id %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>


      <%= link_to "Enroll", [@task.project, @task], :onclick => "$('#project_form').submit() "%>

      <% end %>
```

subs_controller.rb

```
class SubsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @subz = Sub.create(sub_params)
    project = @subz.project

    redirect_to root_path
  end





  private


    def sub_params
      params.require(:sub).permit(:project_id, :user_id)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i came up with the following solution:

I've added the sub handling to the application_controller, so that its availiable for the project_controller. I also added the project, tasks as a reference, so that i am able to redirect to a task via the sub_controller, instead of the project_controller.

application_controller.rb

```
def create
    @subs = Sub.new(sub_params)
    project = @subs.project
    taskz = project.tasks.first
    if @subs.save
        redirect_to [taskz.project, taskz]
    end
  end


  private
    def sub_params
      params.require(:sub).permit(:project_id, :user_id)
    end
```

Inside the show.html.erb from the project_controller, i use the old form:

```
<%= form_for([@project, @subz] do |f| %>



    <%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => @project.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
    <%= f.submit "Submitted" %>


  <% end %>
```

which works fine. Thanks for any previous help!

Answer (score 1):

You can be using the existing form and link_to, just edit some like edit the dorm_tag like this

```
<%= form_for([@project, @subzz], html: {role: "form", id: "project_form"}) do |f| %>
```

and remove the button into form like this one

```
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

and edit the `link_to` like this

```
<%= link_to 'Enroll', "", :onclick => "$('#project_form').submit()" %>
```

it will work

**Update**

You can achieve this without a form, comment out this form and edit the link like below

```
<%= link_to 'Enroll', subs_path(project_id: @project.id, user_id: current_user.id), method: :post %>
```

and the create method update like below

```
def create
    @subz = Sub.new(sub_params)
    if @subz.save
        flash[:success] = 'Sub was successfully submited.'
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        flash[:danger] = 'Sub not submited'
        redirect_to request.referer
    end
end
```

that is easier

Or if you keep before one with form then the link out from the form and the `create` method edit like the following

```
def create
    @subz = Sub.new(sub_params)
    if @subz.save
        flash[:success] = 'Sub was successfully submited.'
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        flash[:danger] = 'Sub not submited'
        redirect_to request.referer
    end
end
```

and the form will look like this

```
<%= form_for([@project, @subzz], html: {role: "form", id: "project_form"}) do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :project_id, :value => @project.id %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Enroll", [@task.project, @task], :onclick => "$('#project_form').submit() "%>
```

if you confused this `[@task.project, @task]` on link tag then use direct link

Comment: Somehow, i get now a params missing error. Any ideas? (Posted the error in the OP post)

Comment: @Prometheus See the ***Update*** section in the answer

Comment: What's happening? have you helped with this answer?

Comment: Both solutions didn't work. I need a link to my tasks that are associated with my projects. I also want to subscribe users to my project at the same time, via the subs_controller.rb, because i use has_many :users, through: subscriptions. In this case, i can't use the first solution because i don't render them with my subs_controller, but with my project_controller. The second solution still gave me the missing param problem. I came up with a tweak, with your help. I posted it down below